# Grails Plugin project - can't find groovy jar when I'm offline

Tags: grails, groovy, dependency-management

I'm using GGTS 3.1, Grails 2.1.1 and Groovy 1.8.6

I created a new workspace, and created a new Grails Plugin project. 
All was fine until yesterday when I was travelling and I did a refresh-dependencies. It failed because the groovy.jar could not be found locally. I spent a long time trying to work out what was happening, but I can't. I have no problems refreshing on any of my application projects, just my (first) plugin project. Here is a extract from the log:

```
Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/%5B1.5,1.7%5D/groovy-%5B1.5,1.7%5D.jar
    module not found: org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]
==== grailsPlugins: tried
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  E:\workspaces\GGTS_310\SchemaMigrationPlugin\SchemaMigration/lib/groovy-[revision].jar
  [all-1.8.8]     C:\Users\JohnO\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SchemaMigration\plugins\database-migration-1.3.2/lib/groovy-[revision].jar
  C:\Users\JohnO\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SchemaMigration\plugins\release-2.0.3/lib/groovy-[revision].jar   C:\Users\JohnO\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SchemaMigration\plugins\rest-client-builder-1.0.2/lib/groovy-[revision].jar
  C:\Users\JohnO\.grails\2.1.1\projects\SchemaMigration\plugins\tomcat-2.1.1/lib/groovy-[revision].jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/ivy-[revision].xml
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/jars/groovy-[revision].jar
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/bundles/groovy-[revision].jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/groovy-[revision].xml
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1\src\libs/groovy-[revision].jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1\dist/groovy-[revision].xml
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1\dist/groovy-[revision].jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  C:\Users\JohnO\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/groovy-[revision].xml
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  C:\Users\JohnO\.grails\2.1.1\cached-installed-plugins/groovy-[revision].jar
==== grailsHome: tried
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1/plugins/groovy-[revision].jar
==== grailsCentral: tried
.....
.....
==== localMavenResolver: tried
  C:\Users\JohnO/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/[revision]/groovy-[revision].pom
  -- artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:
  C:\Users\JohnO/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/[revision]/groovy-[revision].jar
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::      
    :: org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]: not found
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I am not familiar with the syntax: "*org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;[1.5,1.7]!groovy.jar:*", but my best guess is that it is looking for a version that is between 1.5 and 1.7. If so, why? How might I cure this?

The GGTS Preferences for Groovy compiler are set to 1.8.6.xx-20....

There are Groovy jars installed in:

C:\Apps\GGTS310\grails-2.1.1\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-1.8.8.jar

%GRAILS_ROOT%\ivy-cache\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars holds groovy-all-1.8.6.jar and groovy-all.1.8.8.jar

%GRAILS_ROOT%\ivy-cache\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy\jars\groovy-1.7-rc-2.jar

As I said, I don't have this problem refreshing from local resources for any of my Grails projects, just the Plugin project.

John

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin [depends](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#ivy), probably transitively, on org.codehaus.groovy:groovy with [version range](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges) [1.5,1.7].
Notice that this is different from org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all.
None of the options you mentioned answer this dependency.
You can track the origin of this dependency by running the [Grails dependency-report command](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html)

Comment: drorb, many thanks. The dependency-report is great, but I struggle to interpret some things. The heading is _SchemaMigration 2.1.1 by org.grails.internal_ - which is the name of my plugin, but why 2.1.1 and 'grails internal'? There is a _groovy.modules.http-builder_ which requires _groovy 1.7-rc-2_ which asks for revisions _1.5 to 1.7_. This is only for **build** all the rest use _groovy-all_. What can I do about this? I would have thought this as a dependency would be held in my local ivy cache in Grails. John

Comment: Look at the app.version inside the application.properties file, this should be your plugin version. You can exclude the dependency of http-builder on groovy. Look at [Excluding specific transitive dependencies](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies)